# NGINX location regex not working as per expectation

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a sub url that redirects traffic to a particular port. For example: 
if my URL is /a/status, it should redirect to 127.0.0.1:8800/status.

I have tried to configure URL regex but it does not seem to work. Below are the findings so far:

```
location /
    {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
```

For the above code, URL /status, redirects traffic to 8800 port correctly. However, with the code below, there are problems.

```
location /a/
    {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
```

The URL /a/status, does not redirect to port 8800. I also tried using regex like below code but did not work:

```
location ~* ^/(.+)/$
    {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8787;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com;

  # considering /a/status
  # if you want to for any prefix go with "location ~ \/(.+)\/status"
  location = /a/status {
    # there are ways to dynamically rewrite depending on prefix, comment if that part is needed as well
    rewrite ^ /status last;
  }

  location = /status {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800; 
  }
}

server {
  listen 8800;
  location / {
    return 201;
  }
}
```

when we curl it we see that it goes to 8800 server:

```
# curl -I localhost/a/status -H "host: test.com"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 14:08:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
location ^~ /a/status {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If- 
    Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8800;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```